# SOQL for casecomment commentbody returns no results in apex

Tags: apex, soql

When i execute this query through the developer console I get results

```
select parentid from CaseComment where commentbody LIKE '%glitches%'
```

but when I do the exact same query with apex I get no results.

```
string st = '\'%' + srchText + '%\'';
CaseComment[] ccids = [select parentid from CaseComment where commentbody LIKE :st];
```

When I examine the variable and write these to the debug log it looks fine but returns no results

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this without escape characters:

```
string st = '%' + srchText + '%';
CaseComment[] ccids = [select parentid from CaseComment where commentbody LIKE :st];
```

In Debug log it will return like this:

```
[{"ParentId":"5007A000003eJQHQA2","Id":"00a7A000000Q38kQAC"}]
```

Comment: Ah it's a security issue on casecomment object for the portal user. Stink!. Thanks for your help though. When i ran it as me it works fine now. Thanks for your help Santanu

Comment: I mean community user

Comment: After I fixed the code like your suggestion I then discovered that the reason they saw no results as a community user is none of the comments with the search word in it where marked public. Once I made them public everything works fine. Thanks again Santanu